# $ xclock PuTTY X11 proxy: unable to connect to forwarded X server: Network error: Connection refused Error: Can't open display: XX.XX.XXX.XX:10.0

Tags: linux, redhat, rhel7, x11

I getting below error when running xclock command to one RHEL 7 server

```
$ xclock 
PuTTY X11 proxy: unable to connect to forwarded X server: Network error: Connection refused Error: Can't open display: XX.XX.XXX.XX:10.0
```

I did set below setting in `/etc/ssh/sshd_config`

```
X11Forwarding yes
X11DisplayOffset 10
X11UseLocalhost no
```

I have tried with `X11UseLocalhost Yes` or even with commented it out but no luck

I tried with setting `ForwardX11Trusted yes` in  cat

```
/home/user/.ssh/config
```

I am trying to connect from putty which is on my window 10 laptop . I did below setting in putty while connecting sever

```
selected - Enable X11 forwarding
selected - Remote x11 authentication protocol as -- MIT-magic-cookie-1
```

But no luck with above settings

Due security restriction I can't download any software like xming in my window laptop , also I don't have any other linux server from where I can ssh this server

Its very urgent for me   please help me

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have X server running. Check this error:

```
Can't open display: XX.XX.XXX.XX:10.0
```

So ask your manager to permit you to use external software. Or do the work with command line tools

Comment: thanks you very much for response  !! Where I have to install x server ? In my laptop or  in  the server where I am trying to run xclock ?I have already installed xwindow in linux server

Comment: Because your display is your laptop you should install X server on the laptop. You do not need to have X server started/installed on linux to visualize X application on your laptop

Comment: Thanks I  tested with another folk who has xming server installed in his laptop and it worked fine for him . thanks again